# How to modify maintenance plan using T-SQL script in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, maintenance-plans

How can I modify a maintenance plan in SQL Server 2008 using a T-SQL script?

I want to change the schedule of a maintenance plan and change the path of the `.bak` file .

All these changes should be done using a T-SQL script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 parts to this question, I'll treat them one by one.

**Modifying the schedule**

Modifying the schedule isn't really changing the maintenance plan as much as changing the SQL Agent schedule.

Have a look at [sp_update_schedule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187354.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for this need.

**Modifying the Maintenance plan itself**

This will be hard using pure T-SQL as the maintenance plan is stored as an SSIS package. You will have to resort to CLR integration for this.

If you want to do that you would have to export the package from the SSIS package store. (see [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9cc6a819-e7b5-40a2-b5b6-0957118ffed7/modify-ssis-package-saved-on-server)) and then modify them through c#.

See [Building Packages Programmatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345167.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [Modifying an SSIS Package through code](http://www.bimonkey.com/2010/09/modifying-an-ssis-package-through-code/)